# skrape.it error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: kotlin, ktor-client

I am very new to skrape.it and try to do a simple request with it.

When using the `HttpFetcher`, I get the following error as soon as the `response` block is present:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/ktor/client/features/HttpTimeout
```

The function I wrote looks like this:

```kotlin
fun getDocumentByUrl(urlToScrape: String) = skrape(HttpFetcher) {
    request {
        url = urlToScrape
        timeout = 10000
    }
    response {
        htmlDocument {
            div(".title_table_routenliste") { findAll {}}
        }
    }
}
```

Without the `response` block, the request itself works fine.

In my dependencies I added these two lines:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("it.skrape:skrapeit:1.2.2")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of ktor are you using?

Comment: I use ktor version `2.0.3`

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4204/javalangClassNotFoundException-ioktorclientfeaturesHttpTimeout

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helped. Tried version 1.3 alpha of skrape.it and now it works.